# Unable to call public async Task<IActionResult> using $.getJSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a asp.net core mvc project, in which one of the controller contains following method,

```
public class DetailsController : Controller
    {
public async Task<IActionResult> getEvents([FromQuery]string a, [FromQuery]string b)
          {
                ...
    
                return Json(result);
            }
}
```

I am using $.getJSON method to access it, but browser always return error 404:

```
$.getJSON('/Details/getEvents?a=1&b=2')
```

I have tried hitting this url in browser, but it throws following error:
No webpage was found for the web address:
https://www.example.com/Details/getEvents?a=1&b=2
HTTP ERROR 404

*****  **Update** *****
Route configuration

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: I used mvc4.1.1,and it can use `$.getJSON('/Details/getEvents?a=1&b=2')` to get json correctly.

Answer (score 0):

By default, MVC does not allow you to respond to an HTTP GET request with a JSON payload. If you need to send JSON in response to a GET, you'll need to explicitly allow the behavior by using `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` as the second parameter to the `Json()` method:

```cs
public class DetailsController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> getEvents([FromQuery]string a, [FromQuery]string b)
    {
        ...
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but here I am getting 404 on calling this method from javascript.

Comment: Then you might need to show us how you configure the routings. One thing you can try is, instead of manually putting the url as a string, using `@Url.Action("getEvents", "details", new { area = "" })`.

Comment: Updated the question with route configuration.